# Python Selenium Message: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, forms, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Im developing a web scraper in Python which only take user and password from a mysql database and then it goes to a web page and fill out the form to login, until here everything works fine, the problem is when I have more than 1 user in my database, it logs in and fully complete the script but when it passes to the second user it stops at the middle of the code and displays the next message:

**Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"submit"}**

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", db="seliso")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    rfc = row[1]
    clave = row[2]

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://login.siat.sat.gob.mx/nidp/idff/sso?id=mat-ptsc-totp&sid=10&option=credential&sid=10")

    username = driver.find_element_by_name("Ecom_User_ID")
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("Ecom_Password")

    username.send_keys(rfc)
    password.send_keys(clave)

    submit = driver.find_element_by_name("submit")

    submit.click()

    driver.get("https://www.siat.sat.gob.mx/PTSC/")

    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Buzón tributario")
    link.click()

    driver.get("https://www.siat.sat.gob.mx/PTSC/cerrarSesion")

    driver.close()

db.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the name of the button you are trying to click is not called "submit", so there seems to be no element with that name so it fails.  Can you find the name using the browser dev tools?

Comment: Actually, since its on the second iteration - it sounds like you are not getting to the same page with the login form. It could be the session is not closing. Did you try repeating the process manually?